# iPad "album flip" animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-animation

I'm trying to recreate the flipping album animation in iPod.app on the iPad (Music.app in iOS 5). Getting the flipping to work is easy, but I'm having trouble with positioning and enlarging the album. Right now I'm using this code:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.containerView duration:5.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews animations:^(void) {
    self.firstView.hidden = YES;
    self.secondView.hidden = NO;
    self.containerView.frame = CGRectMake(600.0, 0.0, 168.0, 1004.0);
} completion:nil];
```

The flipping works, but there is something strange going on in the animation. The container view does indeed move and resize, but the subviews (firstView and secondView) do not.

Because the superview clips to its bounds (even though I set that to NO; another strange thing!), it appears like the subviews are getting "cut" when the container view moves.

I hope you guys understand the problem. Any Core Animation hero who can help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the autoresize mask on the child views? Those are used to automatically resize or reposition a view when its superview’s bounds change.

Comment: Try adding and removing the subviews instead of hiding them.

Comment: Still the same problem, unfortunately.